# Why did Kano ask this question about air supply?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), Kano meets his old partner, Kabal, who is wearing
mask and iron lung:

> Kano: I am the Black Dragon.
>
> Kabal: Which one's your boss? Let me guess. The blonde?
>
> Kano: **That mask cutting off your air supply, you dumb prick?** I don't
> take orders from anyone, Kabal.

Why did Kano ask this question about air supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kano is saying that Kabal's question...

> Which one's your boss? Let me guess. The blonde?

... is a stupid question, and sarcastically suggesting that maybe the reason Kabal asked such a stupid question is because his mask is cutting off the supply of oxygen to his brain.